# Product of N independent uniform random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

We have N independent random variables of $X_1 , X_2 , ... X_N$ with uniform distribution $U(0,1)$. the distribution of $Y$ as
$$
Y = \frac{1}{X_1X_2X_3 ... X_N}
$$
is desired. 
To solve this problem, I write:
$$
T = \ln(Y) = - \sum_{i=1}^N \ln(X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^N Z_i
$$
where $ Z_i =-\ln(X_i) $. Then the distribution of $Z_i$ random variables could be written as
$$
f_{Z_i}(Z_i) = \frac{f_{X_i}(e^{-Z_i})}{|e^{Z_i}|} = e^{-Z_i}f_{X_i}(e^{-Z_i})
$$
But I do not know how to solve it any further. Would be helpful to utilize its Characteristic function in order to rewrite the sum of natural-log sum of random variables? Or Should I solve it in a different way? 
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted,

$$logY=\Sigma_i (-logX_i)$$

$$W_i=-logX_i\sim Exp(1)$$

Thus $log(Y)=\Sigma_i W_i\sim Gamma(n;1)$

Now, knowing the distribution of $logY$ it is easy to find the requested density

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{log^{n-1}y}{\Gamma(n)y^2}\cdot \mathbb{1}_{(1;+\infty)}(y)$$

---

P.S.: I used the notation $log$ but Natural logarithm is meant

Answer (score 0):

I've found another answer for this question, for whom get here by search.

If we have
$$
\phi_T(s) = E\{e^{sT}\} = E\{e^{s\sum_{i=0}^N Z_i}\} = \prod_{i=0}^NE\{e^{sZ_i}\} 
$$
$$
= \prod_{i=0}^N\phi_{Z_i}(s) = \left( \phi_{Z_i}(s)\right)^N = (\frac{1}{1-s})^N
$$
in Laplace transform, there is this duality
$$
f_T(t) \leftrightarrow L^{-1}\{\phi_T(-s)\} \rightarrow f_T(t) = \frac{1}{(N-1)!}t^{N-1}e^{-t}u(t)
$$
So finally we could write this
$$
T = \ln(Y) \rightarrow Y = e^T 
$$
$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{f_T(\ln(y))}{|e^{\ln(y)}|} =  \frac{1}{(N-1)!}\frac{(\ln(y))^{N-1}}{y^2}u(y-1)
$$